# MySite: An error occurred trying to save your profile

Tags: my-site

after setting up the MySite Host under SP2010. I have edited my profile just to see how if everthing works.
Now to days later I've been told, the users cannot save the changes they made to their profiles.

When the user hits save he gets the error

> An error occurred trying to save your profile.

I found no information on what could be causing this and to resolve it.

Kind regards.

Comment: what do your ULS logs say at the time it errors?

Comment: have to check, once I'm at the office again. This whole thing got somewhat complicated, due to the harsh weather. Have to do home office.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting the same thing and wanted to follow up.